# Prove binary relation is equivalent

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am having trouble in proving that the relation down below is a transitive one:
aRb if and only if ab is a square over the set N*.
Can somebody offer any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a R b$ and $b R c$, then $ab$ and $bc$ are both squares of integers : $ab=p^2$, $bc=q^2$. Then $ab^2c=(pq)^2$ is also a square. This can be true only if $ac$ is a square.

Comment: Okay got it. Thank you